# Seating groups of people on tables in a restaurant Sorting algorithms

Tags: python, arrays, sorting

I am trying to solve this problem which came up in a programming interview exam.

Here is the problem:

---

There are a number of tables in a restaurant (**n**) that can seat a group of people (**m**). The groups range in different sizes. In the following example there are 2 groups of people, one group of 7 and one group of 3 people. In the restaurant there are a total of 4 tables of various sizes which can seat 4, 5 ,1 and 1 peoples.

A group of people can be split and seated at different tables, however table sharing is not possible (different groups cannot share tables with each other).

A group can be turned away if it is not possible to seat them in the restaurant but turning a group away impacts the restaurant's reputation. The formula for the turned away group is `reputation = (bi*x)` where:

- x = 8 (a constant)
- bi = number of people in the group

Splitting a group of people over different tables impacts the restaurant's reputation but this is less than if a group is turned away completely.

`reputation = (k-1)*y` where:

- y = 3 (a constant)
- k = number of tables used to split a group of people.

---

Giving the following data I need to work out an algorithm which can efficiently seat a group of people and will have the lowest impact on the restaurants reputation.

m = 2
groups = [7,3]

n = 4
tables = [4,5,1,1]

I tried to solve the problem using 2 nested for loops but it gets complicated and messy. Here is the code I tried to use but it doesn't work and has lots of errors please help me and tell me if there's a more efficient way to solve this. This is my code:

```
def perfectWaitingStaff(x, y, nTables, mGroups):

    popularity = 0

    # initalise the temp variables
    tempGroups = []
    tempTables = []
    kTables = []  # Stores the groups seated values
    gTurned = []

    # Loop through groups
    for j in range(len(mGroups)):

        # Select the current group to find a table for
        currntGrpIndex = j

        for i in range(len(nTables)):

            # refresh array values
            tempGroups = mGroups.copy()
            tempTables = nTables.copy()

            # Select a seat for the group
            currntTableIndex = i
            seatedGroup = tempGroups[currntGrpIndex]

            # Keep looping until all groups have been seated
            while len(tempTables) > 0:

                # See if the selected group can be seated
                seatedGroup -= tempTables[currntTableIndex]

                # Add table to the group
                kTables.append(tempTables[currntTableIndex])

                # Remove table from the list
                tempTables.pop(currntTableIndex)

                # If seated group is greater than or equal to 0 then allocate more tables to the group
                if seatedGroup <= 0:

                    # Get the length of the groups
                    k = len(kTables)

                    # Calculate the popularity rating
                    popularity += (k - 1) * y

                    # Clear kTables
                    kTables = []

                    # Remove current group from the list
                    tempGroups.pop(currntGrpIndex)

                    # reset the index counters for both groups
                    currntGrpIndex = 0
                    currntTableIndex = 0

                    # Get remaining groups in array
                    if tempGroups is not None:
                        seatedGroup = tempGroups[currntGrpIndex]

                # if the length of tempTables is equal to length of groups
                if currntTableIndex == len(tempTables):
                    gTurned.append(tempGroups[currntGrpIndex])
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.